# Java -How to know what has been eliminated HashSet?

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

How to know what has been eliminated HashSet ?

I have an array `int [] x = {2, 4, 4, 5};`

When I covert it, `HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(x));`

How do I know what elements have been eliminated from `x` into `set` ?

Comment: There is no way to say the first or second `4` was eliminated as they are equal.

Comment: No dude, in this case I just want "4" @PeterLawrey

Comment: In that case; you should check as you add them see Jon Skeet's answer. Note: you can get duplicate, duplicates if there three 4's for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using that constructor, you could use:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int value : x) {
    if (!set.add(value)) {
        // Or whatever you want to do
        System.out.println("Detected a duplicate... " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so `set.add` returns boolean ?

Comment: Yes, it returns `true` in case of success, otherwise `false`.

Comment: @TilakMadichetti: Did you look at the documentation to check, and understand the return value? (Stack Overflow is *not* an alternative to reading documentation yourself.)

Comment: Yep I know that S.O is not an alternative!

Comment: @TilakMadichetti: So rather than ask in a comment for something you could have checked for yourself, you should have done so. Learning to do research yourself is a very important skill for a software engineer.

Comment: I am Sorry and I'll try to improve. Now I am 14 and I got 4 more years to learn and become a successful person. @JonSkeet Thanks by the way for advice !!

Comment: @TilakMadichetti Try [this site](http://www.grepcode.com) to check the source codes at the same time as the Javadocs.

Comment: @TilakMadichetti I have been programming professionally for 24 years, and I am still learning to be a successful person ;)

Comment: Oh no I never said I'll stop Learning at 18 @peter

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what Jon Skeet mentioned, if you are looking for something generic, then here are my possible approaches:

1. Find the duplicates in the array, and those can be considered as the values that were removed from the HashSet. This doesn't really have to do anything with the HashSet though.

Example:

```
Arrays.sort( myArray);
for ( int i = 1; i < myArray.length; ++i ) {
  if ( 0 == myComparator.compare( myArray[i - 1], myArray[i] )) {
     // Found a duplicate. Store/print it
  }
}
```

2. Extend the `HashSet` class and override the `add(Object obj)` method so that when the object is already present in the HashSet it is added to a list of removed items. Of course, this means you will have to use this custom `HashSet` wherever you want to use `HashSet`.

Example:

```
public MyHashSet extends HashSet<E> {
 List<E> removedAsDuplicateItems = new ArrayList<>();

 @Override
 public boolean add(E e) {
    boolean isNewItem = map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    if(!isNewItem) removedAsDuplicateItems.add(e);
    return isNewItek;
 }

 public List<E> removedAsDuplicateItems() {
  return removedAsDuplicateItems;
 }
}
```

I hope there is much more elegant and concise solution that I am unaware of.